# I get a Nan error certainly due to my render() business logic

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make an addition/substraction game that consists of answering three Level 1 additions first and then, the game moves on to Level 1 substractions. I'm certain that the render() section's business logic can be much improved. Could you please help me on how you would go about structuring that logic? Thanks.

```
<div id="app" />
    <script type="text/babel">
        // class Winner extends React.Component {
        //     render() {
        //         return (
        //             <div id="winner">
        //                 You win {this.props.name}!
        //                 Your score: {this.props.scoreAddLevel1}!
        //            </div>
        //         );
        //     }
        // }
        class App extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    addLevel1Num1: 1,
                    addLevel1Num2: 1,
                    subLevel1Num1: 1,
                    subLevel1Num2: 1,
                    response: "",
                    incorrect: false,
                    scoreAddLevel1: 0,
                    scoreSubLevel1: 0
                };
            }
            render() {
                if (this.state.scoreAddLevel1 === 3) {
                    return this.renderWinAddLevel1();
                    return this.renderProblemSubLevel1();
                }
                else if (this.state.scoreSubLevel1 === 3) {
                    return this.renderWinSubLevel1();
                } else {
                    return this.renderProblemAddLevel1();
                }
            }
            renderProblemAddLevel1() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h1 id="mainTitle">Welcome to the Review Game Area!</h1>
                        <div id="problem" className={this.state.incorrect ? "incorrect" : ""}>
                            {this.state.addLevel1Num1} + {this.state.addLevel1Num2} = <input onKeyPress={this.inputKeyPressAddLevel1} onChange={this.updateResponse} value={this.state.response} class="resizedTextBox"/>
                           Score: {this.state.scoreAddLevel1} <button onClick={this.resetLineAddLevel1} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Line</button> <button onClick={this.resetFullGame} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Full Game</button>


                        </div>
                        <div id="timer">00:00:00</div>


                    </div>

                );
            }



            renderWinAddLevel1() {

                return (
                    <div>
                        <h1 id="mainTitle">Welcome to the Review Game Area!</h1>
                        <div id="problem" className={this.state.incorrect ? "incorrect" : ""}>
                            <img src={'./green-leaf.svg'} />
                           Score: {this.state.scoreAddLevel1} <button onClick={this.resetFullGame} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Full Game</button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="problem" className={this.state.incorrect ? "incorrect" : ""}>
                            {this.state.subLevel1Num1} - {this.state.subLevel1Num2} = <input onKeyPress={this.inputKeyPressSubLevel1} onChange={this.updateResponse} value={this.state.response} class="resizedTextBox"/>
                           Score: {this.state.scoreSubLevel1} <button onClick={this.resetFullGame} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Line</button> <button onClick={this.resetFullGame} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Full Game</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                );

                // const name = "the addition game";
                // const score = {score};
                // return (
                //     <Winner name={name} score={score}/>
                // );
            }

            renderProblemSubLevel1() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h1 id="mainTitle">Welcome to the Review Game Area!</h1>
                        <div id="problem" className={this.state.incorrect ? "incorrect" : ""}>
                            {this.state.subLevel1Num1} - {this.state.subLevel1Num2} = <input onKeyPress={this.inputKeyPressSubLevel1} onChange={this.updateResponse} value={this.state.response} class="resizedTextBox"/>
                           Score: {this.state.scoreSubLevel1} <button onClick={this.resetLineSubLevel1} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Line</button> <button onClick={this.resetFullGame} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Full Game</button>


                        </div>



                    </div>

                );
            }



            renderWinSubLevel1() {

                return (
                    <div>
                        <h1 id="mainTitle">Welcome to the Review Game Area!</h1>
                        <div id="problem" className={this.state.incorrect ? "incorrect" : ""}>
                            <img src={'./green-leaf.svg'} />
                           Score: {this.state.scoreSubLevel1} <button onClick={this.resetFullGame} class="btn btn-primary">Reset Full Game</button>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                );

                // const name = "the addition game";
                // const score = {score};
                // return (
                //     <Winner name={name} score={score}/>
                // );
            }

            updateResponse = (event) => {
                this.setState({ response: event.target.value });
            }
            inputKeyPressAddLevel1 = (event) => {
                if (event.key === "Enter") {
                    const answer = parseInt(this.state.response);
                    if (answer === this.state.addLevel1Num1 + this.state.addLevel1Num2) {
                        this.setState(state => ({
                            addLevel1Num1: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + state.scoreAddLevel1,
                            addLevel1Num2: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + state.scoreAddLevel1,
                            // subLevel1Num1: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + state.scoreSubLevel1,
                            // subLevel1Num2: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + state.scoreSubLevel2,
                            response: "",
                            incorrect: false,
                            scoreAddLevel1: state.scoreAddLevel1 + 1
                            // scoreSubLevel1: state.scoreSubLevel1 + 1
                        }));
                    } else {
                        this.setState({
                            response: "",
                            incorrect: true
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            inputKeyPressSubLevel1 = (event) => {
                if (event.key === "Enter") {
                    const answer = parseInt(this.state.response);
                    if (answer === this.state.subLevel1Num1 - this.state.subLevel1Num2) {
                        this.setState(state => ({
                            subLevel1Num1: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + state.scoreSubLevel1,
                            subLevel1Num2: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + state.scoreSubLevel2,
                            response: "",
                            incorrect: false,
                            scoreSubLevel1: state.scoreSubLevel1 + 1
                        }));
                    } else {
                        this.setState({
                            response: "",
                            incorrect: true
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            resetFullGame = (event) => {
                this.setState({
                    addLevel1Num1: 1,
                    addLevel1Num2: 1,
                    subLevel1Num1: 1,
                    subLevel1Num2: 1,
                    response: "",
                    incorrect: false,
                    scoreAddLevel1: 0,
                    // scoreSubLevel1: 0
                });
            }

            resetLineAddLevel1 = (event) => {
                this.setState({
                    addLevel1Num1: 1,
                    addLevel1Num2: 1,
                    response: "",
                    incorrect: false
                });
            }

            resetLineSubLevel1 = (event) => {
                this.setState({
                    subLevel1Num1: 1,
                    subLevel1Num2: 1,
                    response: "",
                    incorrect: false
                });
            }
        }

        ReactDOM.render((
            <div>
                <App />
            </div>
        ), document.querySelector("#app"));
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My general advice would be to use the conditional in your `render` function to render React DOM nodes, not call functions. It would look like this:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.scoreAddLevel1 === 3) {
    return <ProblemSubLevel1 />;
  } else if (this.state.scoreSubLevel1 === 3) {
    return <WinSubLevel1 />;
  } else {
    return <ProblemAddLevel1 />;
  }
}
```

Each component is defined outside of `App`.

Render each of these components into your browser outside the conditional, and get them looking and behaving the way you want. When each component can load and not crash with errors in the browser, then work on rendering them conditionally.

[render docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render)

Comment: Thanks Jake, I'm going to look into this and get back to you asap.

Comment: A question. Does <ProblemAddLevel1 /> have to be created as a separate class from the <App /> class or does it have to be created as being part of the <App /> class?

Comment: My question is not only about <ProblemAddLevel1 /> but also <ProblemSubLevel1 /> and <WinSubLevel1 />.

Comment: I'm thinking that the if statement will return a component or another depending on the condition layout. Isn't it possible to have that if statement not return just one problem but kind of chain them together like after one problem was successful, we move on to another?

Comment: First question: each React component should be defined as its own separate function or class, and in the opinion of some, JavaScript file. This will make the components easier to iterate on, read, and test. It will prevent React from re-defining your functions every time `render` is called, which might be a lot of times.

Comment: Second question: using a `switch` or `if` / `else`, any number of components can be conditionally rendered based on the state of `App`. Each child could receive an `advanceLevel` function as a prop; each level decides if its criteria has been met to calls the function, incrementing a `level` state count and showing a new level to the user.

Comment: Thanks again Jake! I'll take some time to reorganize my code. I made a version which is based on function calls (before I saw your two last posts), which works great, but as you said, your way would facilitate code reuse. So I may need to investigate further. Your messages definitely answer my questions. Thanks for everything.

Comment: Actually, my code is meant to be gradual, so if I were to put the different render() into React components (i.e. a class for each render), I would lose the progress as the challenge initially consists of answering random test questions from 1 to 15 questions one after the other. Or maybe I just don't see how I can start implementing what you explained.